# C++ ZBar cmake error 'File not found' when including

Tags: c++, cmake, zbar

I have a problem when I include `ZBar` in my C++ script. I already tried adding it via a `CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project( Barcode-cpp )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ZBARCV_SOURCE_DIR} )
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${ZBARCV_SOURCE_DIRS})
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
add_library( src
        src/VideoVeed.h
        src/VideoVeed.cpp
        src/Crop.h
        src/Crop.cpp
        src/Barcodes.h
        src/Barcodes.cpp
)
add_executable( program
            program/main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries( program src ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${ZBAR_LIBRARIES} zbar )
```

I'm on mac. I looked and my `zbar.h` file is located in `/usr/local/include/` where it's supposed to be.

I include it like this: `#include <zbar.h>`

I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

***Full make error log:***

```
/Users/mathijs/Documents/Barcode-cpp/src/Barcodes.h:7:10: fatal error: 'zbar.h' file not found
#include <zbar.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/src.dir/src/VideoVeed.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/src.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you please provide the **full** `make` error log in the question post? Also, you don't seem to *define* your `ZBAR*` variables anywhere? Are these defined by OpenCV? You can test this by trying `message("ZBARCV_SOURCE_DIR: ${ZBARCV_SOURCE_DIR}")` in your CMake file...

Comment: @squareskittles make error in question

Comment: @squareskittles It doesn't find the ZBAR lib, when adding that message

Comment: As @squareskittles, you do not set any of the ZBAR variables anywhere in your code. Do you expect CMake to automatically figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked; the Brew package for ZBar includes a packageconfig file (`zbar.pc`)

That means you can use modern CMake tooling instead of cargo culting:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project( Barcode-cpp )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library( src
        src/VideoVeed.h
        src/VideoVeed.cpp
        src/Crop.h
        src/Crop.cpp
        src/Barcodes.h
        src/Barcodes.cpp
)
add_executable( program
            program/main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(program src ${OpenCV_LIBS})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(ZBar REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET zbar)

target_link_libraries(program PkgConfig::ZBar)
```

The `pkg_check_modules` will read the `zbar.pc` file and generate an `IMPORTED` target named `PkgConfig::ZBar` that will automatically set both include paths and linker paths for `program`.

Comment: Do you perhaps know why I can't include zbar in a C++ script inside src, but I can in main.cpp?

Comment: Only the  `program` target is linked to it. But you can use `target_link_libraries(src PkgConfig::ZBar)` to also link `src`. I believe the link to `program` is not even necessary then.

Comment: Thanks, the link to program is indeed not necessary.